# Inheriting a static class in order to override members

Tags: c#, inheritance, static-methods, sql-delete, system.io.directory

I'm looking to override the System.IO.Directory class specifically so I can override the Delete method since I am getting an error that says the "directory is not empty".  I want to preserve all the other methods of the class, just add some additional logic to the code for the Delete method since what appears to be causing the error is a race condition on the server where the file deletion has not been committed on the server before it reports back that all the files have been deleted.

I could write a custom function to do this in another class, but my company produces it's own framework, and I thought it would be useful for other developers that will likely run into this error also.

Can anybody suggest a code pattern that will emulate static inheritance without wrapping each public member of the System.IO.Directory class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You can't override methods that are not designed to be overridden  - this by design.

**Long answer:**

Libraries have inter-dependencies, lets say you have the following loaded dependencies:

```
Main.exe
   | ->  A.dll
   |       |
   |       v
   | ->  B.dll
```

The developer of `A.dll` depends on `B.dll`, and they have a certain expectation of how B.dll will work.

If you were allowed to change the behaviour of B in an undefined way (not using inheritance), then the developer of `A.dll` would not have any confidence that `B.dll` will do what they expect, which would be counter-intuitive and error-prone. (this is also why the `sealed` keyword exists)

This is also true if you consider the .net framework libraries - which have interdependence and expect other .net framework libraries to work in a specific way. It's very likely that other framework classes call `System.IO.Directory.Delete` method for reasons you won't ever even know about, and if you changed how that method works it could break a lot of things.

**Alternatives:**

One suggestion would be to create a `DirectoryEx` class which can statically define your custom `Delete` method there. You would be able to use your custom method in your own code, but other code (not written by you) would still have confidence that the delete method is working how it is expected.

Comment: caesay is right. The Delete method is working as specified. You should fix the race condition by guaranteeing the server responds only after the file deletes are committed.

Comment: Unfortunately our developers don't have the authority to modify company wide server settings and I'm not sure there would even be a setting that could be changed to address this issue.  I had already thought of creating an extension class as ceasay also suggested but would have preferred just to override or shadow the Delete method by creating our own version of the static Directory class to deal with specific issues we experience and then pass through the functionality of the inherited Directory class. All our methods contain notation so no surprises by using the method if published.